# How I can count data according to day?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I do like this to `count job_id`

- `js_id        int`
- `job_id       int`
- `apply_date   smalldatetime`

Code:

```
string cmdstr3 = "SELECT COUNT(job_id) FROM applied_jobs 
                  WHERE js_id='" + jsId + "' AND apply_date='" + DateTime.Now.Date + "'";`

string cmdstr4 = "SELECT COUNT(job_id) FROM applied_jobs 
                  WHERE js_id='" + jsId + "' AND (apply_date >='" + start_date.Date + "' AND apply_date <'" + end_date.Date+ "')";
```

but it counts as `0`

I have data like this

```
3/6/2012 12:00:00 AM
3/6/2012 12:00:00 AM
3/5/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: what's the count when you remove the where clause.

Comment: are you sure you do have data with supplied `jsId` ??/

Comment: @ Conrad Frix: then it meaning less as per my requirement

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to get the count of entries for Current Date of a Certain `js_id`. Here is what simply you should do:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([job_id]) FROM [applied_jobs] WHERE [js_id] = @jsid AND datediff(day,[apply_date], @applydate) = 0",cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@jsid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = jsId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@applydate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Comment: +1 for using **parameters** in the query to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: I have applied code given by Shekhar_Pro but it not works.It evan show `COUNT of job_id=0`.In database i have entry like this'3/5/2012 12:00:00 AM'.I think it  have time also so it can't be compare correctly as i want.

Comment: @jinaljagani for that you can simply ignore the time part by using the TSQl datediff function and compare it only with the date... Hope it helps this time :)